# ng-click event not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular JS newbie here. I am trying to make a basic change to a site at work that I did not build.

I added a column to a table on the database that is called display_appraisal. I wanted it to work the same as a column on the table called display.

I literally copy the code for the display function and changed it to display_appraisal from the html file like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-mini" ng-class="{'btn-success': manufacturer.display==1, 'btn-danger': manufacturer.display!=1}" ng-click="manufacturers.change_display($index)"><i class="icon-white" ng-class="{'icon-ok': manufacturer.display==1, 'icon-remove': manufacturer.display!=1}"></i></button>
<button class="btn btn-mini" ng-class="{'btn-success': manufacturer.display_appraisal==1, 'btn-danger': manufacturer.display_appraisal!=1}" ng-click="manufacturers.change_display_appraisal($index)"><i class="icon-white" ng-class="{'icon-ok': manufacturer.display_appraisal==1, 'icon-remove': manufacturer.display_appraisal!=1}"></i></button>
```

then in my ctrl file:

```
change_display: function(index) {
        this.list[index].display = (0 == this.list[index].display) ? 1: 0;
        this.update(index, 'display');
    },
change_display_appraisal: function(index) {
        this.list[index].display_appraisal = (0 == this.list[index].display_appraisal) ? 1: 0;
        this.update(index, 'display_appraisal');

    },
```

The buttons are displaying correctly for the values on the table (success for 1, danger for 1). So I know I am pulling in the data correctly. But for some reason, the ng-click does not work. I also added a text box that I can change the value from 0 to 1 and that works.

```
<input hv-blur ng-change="manufacturers.update($index,'display_appraisal')" placeholder="display_appraisal" type="text" ng-model="manufacturer.display_appraisal">
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Another angular newbie here. Are you sure that your change method wrong? Maybe there is something wrong in the update function? Did you try to debug the click handler with brakepoints?  In a chrome debugger you can set up brakepoints and you can follow the flow of your application.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a plknr with two ways to do what you need.

[Sample](https://embed.plnkr.co/Sfr2yw7n6e8FxYSBNMfu/)

First of all i create a data supposing match with your cause you did not provided the manufaturers array. so.

I put two ways you can change the class of the button.

The first one is using the **ng-class** like this `{'btn-success': manufacturer.display, 'btn-danger': !manufacturer.display}` and **ng-click** `"change_display($index)"`

Second alternative for your `display_appraisal` can do like this

```
ng-class="{true:'btn-success', false:'btn-danger' 
[manufacturer.display_appraisal]" ng-click="manufacturer.display_appraisal = 
!manufacturer.display_appraisal
```

with out necessity of a funciton to change the display_apprasial attr.

Check the sample for more detail.

**SCRIPT**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';


  $scope.change_display = function(index) {
    console.log(index);
      $scope.data[index].display = (false == $scope.data[index].display) ? true: false;

  };

  $scope.data = [
    {
      name:'one',
      display_appraisal : true,
      display : true
    },
    {
      name:'two',
      display_appraisal : false,
      display : true
    },
    {
      name:'three',
      display_appraisal : false,
      display : false
    },
    {
      name:'four',
      display_appraisal : true,
      display : false
    },
    {
      name:'five',
      display_appraisal : false,
      display : false
    }
    ]
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>


    <table class="table table-stripped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>column1</th>
        <th>buttons</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="manufacturer in data">
          <td>{{manufacturer.name}}</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-mini" ng-class="{'btn-success': manufacturer.display, 'btn-danger': !manufacturer.display}" ng-click="change_display($index)"><i class="icon-white" ng-class="{'icon-ok': manufacturer.display==true, 'icon-remove': manufacturer.display==false}"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-mini" ng-class="{true:'btn-success', false:'btn-danger'}[manufacturer.display_appraisal]" ng-click="manufacturer.display_appraisal = !manufacturer.display_appraisal"><i class="icon-white" ng-class="{'icon-ok': manufacturer.display_appraisal==true, 'icon-remove': manufacturer.display_appraisal==false}"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </body>

</html>
```